# Is time varying channels same as circulary symmetric complex gaussian?

Tags: fading-channel

From the literature i understood that if the channel is **non time varying** then we can consider it as **circularly symmetric complex gaussian distributed.** So **can we consider the same** if the **channel is time varying** ?

Comment: What kind of channel are you reading about? You need to be more specific because there are so many (different frequencies, over-the-air, wired, underwater, etc.)

Comment: These are indeed two different notions.

Comment: @Engineer i am considering over the air channel.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the literature i understood that if the channel is non time varying then we can consider it as circularly symmetric complex gaussian distributed.

That's plain wrong. Some non-time-variant channels are $\sim\mathcal{CN}$, some aren't.

> So can we consider the same if the channel is time varying ?

No.

Comment: can you please tell why some are not circularly symmetric complex gaussian distributed. Also if time varying channel can be rayleigh distributed then why cant they be circularly symmetric complex gaussian distributed..

Comment: "can you please tell why some are not circularly symmetric complex gaussian distributed." Because they simply aren't. A channel is a physical thing. Not everything in physics is symmetrically Gaussian.

Comment: "why cant they be circularly symmetric complex gaussian distributed" Read my answer closely: They **can** be. Some channel models imply channels that are, some don't.